# How to remove elements from nested object array?

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to remove elements from nested object array. My document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a79b8a6b2ba9a49359fa3c3"),
    "_class" : "com.PersonEntity",
    "records" : [ 
        {
            "number" : "4905537",
            "label" : "ASH"
        }, 
        {
            "number" : "KM537",
            "label" : "JAP"
        }, 
        {
            "number" : "49537",
            "label" : "JAP"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to delete all the records of all the documents where the record has the label "JAP".

This is the way I'm trying to do it:

```
Update update = new Update().pull("records", new BasicDBObject("label", "JAP"));
mongoOperations.updateMulti(new Query(), update, PersonEntity.class);
```

It seems that there is something wrong with this Update because removing is not working.

Can any body help me with this?

Comment: What is your mongo server and spring mongo jar version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you need to mention the name of the field, before the sub-field ("records.label" instead of "label").

Try this one:

```
Update update = new Update().pull("records", new 
                     BasicDBObject("records.label","JAP"));
```

If this will not do, you may try:

```
Update update = new Update().pull("records", 
                     Collections.singletonMap("label", "JAP"));
```

Comment: Your second proposition works better, I get this as a result: `WriteResult{n=1, updateOfExisting=true, upsertedId=null}`. But it still doesn't save anything in the database :/

Comment: Is "PersonEntity.class" an Enum(represent the ollection name)? Are you sure it reflects the name and nut the numeric value?

Comment: I was missing a `@qualifier` for my `mongoOperations` so it was saving in the wrong database. So using `Collections.singletonMap("label", "JAP")` resolved my problem. Thank you very much! wasted too much time in this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a schema as const

`const Chat = require('./modules/chat/chatModel')`

and your query is like this:

```
    Chat.update({
            _id: ObjectId("5a79b8a6b2ba9a49359fa3c3"),
        }, {
            $pull: {
                records: {
                    label: "ASH"
                },
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also witness same issue but this is little different from accepted answer.

```
Update update = new Update().pull("records", new 
                     BasicDBObject("label","JAP"));
```

As you already mentioned records in key , so you need not write "records.label"